# Does Spies provide Line of sight for my Ally with Cartography?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

According to the Wiki, [Spies](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Spies_%28Age_of_Empires_II%29) is a technology which

> allows a player to see their enemies' Line of Sight.

And [Cartography](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Cartography):

> allows a player to share their allies' Line of Sight.

In this case, if I research Spies, will my ally be able to see my enemies line of sight? If yes, we could split the required gold

Comment: If this is possible, I could split the research cost with my ally

Comment: I don't believe it does but will test it out and come back later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cartography](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Cartography) only provides vision of *allied* units. [Spies](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Spies_(Age_of_Empires_II)) provides vision of *all* units. So, if your ally has Cartography, they can see *your* units. Because the units that you see with Spies aren't *yours*, your ally can't see them.

Remember, Cartography doesn't actually share all allied vision, it just grants you the vision of any allied unit.

Answer (score 0):

No.It's like researching "cartography" for your enemies.You won't share it with allies.

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't. Would be a bit crap if you were about to stab an ally in the back but he could see your spies because of their line of sight.

Comment: He can already see your guys with cartography, though. Spies is completely unrelated.